# What to call a mass of meat in English?

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english

I'm not talking about the meat itself. Could be a corpse or something lifeless.

I think I've heard of the term *"lamb"* (British English). Is that the case though? (as lamb is sheep's meat).

---

**EDIT**:
Eventually the context I heard the word was not *meat* specific. Also the word is *"lump"* as an answer in the comments.

Usage: - I won't stand a chance against a big lump like you ([ref](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lump))

Comment: Depends on the type of meat -- slab, sausage, mound, lump.

Comment: Note that the figurative use is generally something along the lines of "You useless piece/hunk of meat!"

Comment: Definitely not lamb. A lamb is a young sheep, not an amount/mass of meat. Are you sure it wasn't "lump" you heard?

Comment: Can you give an example sentence demonstrating the usage of the word you're looking for? Just use ____ or some other filler where you want the word to be.

Comment: @TimFoster Oh yes! That's it. Looking up "lump" word definition is what I was searching for. Happy to accept it as an answer if you'd submit it below. Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: If you were talking about an animal, Carcass or Carcase (both pronounced /'kɑːrkəs/) may refer to:

    Dressed carcass, the body of a livestock animal ready for butchery, after removal of skin, visceral organs, head, feet etc
    Animal carcass, the dead body of an animal   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carcass

Comment: 'lump' works but is not specific to meat. 'lump of coal', 'lump of dirt', 'a lump on a log'

Comment: These comments bring to mind https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sj_U6vObUA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Lump" can be used to refer to a piece of meat, or generally a pile, collection or large piece of anything.

It can also be used humorously (or insultingly) to refer to a person who is lazy, heavy or slow.

For example, you could say something like

> "Hurry up, you lump of meat!"

or

> "Come over here, you great lump."